# Проблема с кодом бота в дискорде

Tags: python, alias

При запуске бота в дискорде выдаёт ошибку
File "C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\Новая папка (20)\main.py", line 16, in 
async def help(ctx):
File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1263, in decorator
self.add_command(result)
File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1149, in add_command
raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

config = {
'token': 'TOKEN',
'prefix': '>',
'free': '1059502827447267338',
'vip': '1059503060235329617',
'prem': '1059503066354827355',
'adm': '1059503076542787585'
}  

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'])

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
embed=discord.Embed(title=" | Attack")
embed.add_field(name=">free", value=" - бесплатная атака", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=">vip", value=" - вип атака", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=">premium", value=" - премиум атака", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=">admin", value=" - админ атака", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=">methods", value=" - список методов", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=">protocols", value=" - список протоколов", inline=True)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код выдает ошибку т.к. по умолчанию в Discord уже встроена команда help.
Вам необходимо удалить её написав после

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'])
```

Строку:

```
bot.remove_command("help")
```